# Adding "tags" to a Model in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo

Given a custom model named 'Foo', I would like to add "tags" to it.

I am trying the following code, but getting the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "_unknown" does not exist LINE 1:
...rel._unknown_id FROM _unknown_proposal_block_rel, "_unknown"
```

Also, checking psql:

```
select * from ir_model_relation;
...
111 | 2017-10-22 10:51:00.440656 | 2017-10-22 10:51:00.440656 |    359 |   353 | _unknown_foo_rel                         |            |           |            |
```

It can be seen that the names were not properly taken.

The code I am using:

```
class FooTag(models.Model):
    _name = 'foo_tag'
    _description = 'Foo Tag'
    tag = fields.Char('Tag')

class Foo(models.Model):
    _name = 'foo'
    _description = 'Foo Model'
    name = fields.Char('Name', required=True)
    content = fields.Text('Foo Content')
    tag_ids = fields.Many2many('foo.tag', string='Tags')
```

Is this the right way of doing it?

Here is the code for the view:

```
<record id="view_form_foo" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Foo Form</field>
    <field name="model">foo</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Foo">
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="tag_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
                    <field name="content"/>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Any tip is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it is:

```
tag_ids = fields.Many2many('foo_tag', string='Tags')
```

instead of:

```
tag_ids = fields.Many2many('foo.tag', string='Tags')
```